# Checking for successful launch via nohup

Tags: linux, bash, wait, nohup

On one of the servers, I have a script in which at one of the stages tcpdump is sent to nohup.

```
start_dump() {
    2>&1 /usr/bin/nohup /usr/sbin/tcpdump -s 0 -i $IFACE host $HOST -C 1000 -w $DUMP_DIR/$LOGIN/$DATE\_$HOST.pcap | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }' >> /var/log/dump/nohup_$LOGIN.out &
}
```

I need to make sure everything went well and the dump is being written. To do this, I check if the process exists in ps, but in some cases I get an error even though the process exists there.

```
dump_check() {
    ps u -C tcpdump | grep $HOST > /dev/null
}
```

For debugging, I made a cycle of checks, as it seemed to me the reason was that the dump did not have time to start before checking the condition.

```
start_dump() {
    2>&1 /usr/bin/nohup /usr/sbin/tcpdump -s 0 -i $IFACE host $HOST -C 1000 -w $DUMP_DIR/$LOGIN/$DATE\_$HOST.pcap | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }' >> /var/log/dump/nohup_$LOGIN.out &
}

dump_check_check() {
    ps u -C tcpdump | grep $HOST
    echo $?
}

...

                start_dump
                for run in {1..10}; do
                    dump_check_check
                done
```

And apparently I was right. This is what I get:

```
+ start_dump
+ for run in {1..10}
+ dump_check_check
+ grep 172.x.x.x
+ ps u -C tcpdump
+ awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
+ /usr/bin/nohup /usr/sbin/tcpdump -s 0 -i ppp0 host x.x.x.x -C 1000 -w /root/dumps/xxxx/2021-01-21_17:31:51_172.19.5.234.pcap
+ echo 1
1
+ for run in {1..10}
+ dump_check_check
+ grep 172.x.x.x
+ ps u -C tcpdump
+ echo 1
1
+ for run in {1..10}
+ dump_check_check
+ grep 172.x.x.x
+ ps u -C tcpdump
root       768  0.0  0.0  10020  1468 pts/0    D+   17:31   0:00 /usr/sbin/tcpdump -s 0 -i ppp0 host 172.x.x.x -C 1000 -w /root/dumps/xxxx/2021-01-21_17:31:51_172.19.5.234.pcap
+ echo 0
0
```

Firstly, the dump itself starts executing after checking the condition, why?
Secondly, even after the launch, the next check of the condition is also not successful, as I understand it, due to the fact that the command is sent to nohup and the dump does not have time to start before the next check. Well, the third time everything works.

**Question**: it seems that the solution to this is to add a delay before checking the condition, but sleep does not suit me because sometimes the check is performed the first time, and sometimes the fifth time. I can't just waste so much time, it's critical for me.
I am looking for a solution where the success check will run multiple times before success, but no longer than a specific time. If this time expires, an error should appear.

ps *I hope I haven't overdone the details. This is my first question here.
Thanks in advance, friends!*

Comment: It's not clear to me what you do if you find it didn't start properly, other than echo that it failed. if all you want to do is echo that it failed you can just put that inside what nohup calls, like nohup tcpdump ... && echo GOOD yourlogfile.log || echo FAIL >> yourlogfile.log. Since that's getting pretty complicated, I would probably put all that logic in a file and run it like nohup mytcpdump.sh >> /var/log/dump/nohup_$LOGIN.out

Comment: This is not enough. Probably the main problem is that nohup is delayed. If you look at the execution order, you can see that first the start_dump function is called, then the check is performed, and only after it nohup is started.
I cannot understand how this is possible.

Comment: nohup is asynchronous.  It backgrounds near immediately.  If you want to check on the status of what’s happening within nohup, you either need to make it synchronous (by chaining the command to tcpdump) or make it asynchronous by polling for it. Conceptually, those are your options.

Comment: @NicholasRees Can you tell me how to make it synchronous? This would be a perfect solution, but I couldn't find almost anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for a solution where the success check will run multiple times before success, but no longer than a specific time. If this time expires, an error should appear.

You can always use something like this:

```
check_dump()
{
    for run in {1..10}
    do  sleep .1
        ps u -C tcpdump | grep $HOST && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

start_dump
if check_dump; then echo SUCCESS; else echo ERROR; fi
```

This will run no longer than about one second (the time of `ps | grep` should be negligible). You can adjust the maximum number of checks and the interval between them at will.

Comment: Honestly, I could not understand how it is better than a simple `sleep 1`.
I would like multiple checks to be performed only when necessary if they are past fail.
But the main question for me is why nohup is executed out of order:

Comment: You overlook that here the `check_dump` function is finished by the `return 0` as soon as the check succeeds, not only after the maximum time. And your _main question_ is trivial to answer: Because of the `&` it is executed in parallel in the background, and there is no _order_ for that parallel execution.

Comment: I tried to do as you advised, I just run the specified number of checks in a row, `return 1` appears just like a string at the end and the script continues execution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by _I just run the specified number of checks in a row_ (since this is done in `check_dump`) and by _appears just like a string_. Could you post a `set -x` trace of the `check_dump` execution?

Comment: Yes, that's an unfortunate problem. You could try to post it here despite the format loss, or add it (temporarily) to your question or an answer.

Comment: I mean, if I do it according to your example - I always have 10 checks

Comment: Hm - but it doesn't take longer than 1 second for `tcpdump` to appear in the `ps` output, does it? -  You don't see  `ps` output there, do you?

Comment: Not sure I understand you. If we are talking about the total execution time of the test cycle, then yes, about 1 sec. And I was almost desperate and just added sleep 1 after nohup.
I'm reading about until now, it looks like what I need, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does `check_dump` return 0 (success) with this additional _sleep 1_? If so, the `10` times `.1` seem not quite enough, and just one of these numbers needs to be increased. But I doubt that - there's still the unsolved mystery that _`return 1` appears just like a string_.

Comment: I tried increasing to 20, the same result. But I'm sure the check succeeds after 2-3 attempts.
And ye, If I just add sleep 1 the check succeeds.

Comment: Well, as you report, the check, which is the same as your shown check, in `check_dump` does not succeed without the prior sleep (which you want to avoid). It will be tedious to sort this out without a relevant trace.

Comment: You could try https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98569/bin-bash to post the trace.

Comment: In my question, I attached a trace, sleep is not used there and because of this, nohup is executed after checking. If you add sleep - nohup has time to start before checking.
But the problem is that the time it takes for nohup to start is always different and I don't want to always wait for sleep unnecessarily.
Maybe I misunderstand you, my English is not perfect.

Comment: I understood that. The trace I was wishing is not the trace of your solution, but a trace of my `check_dump` function which works for me and doesn't work for you - this would need to be analyzed if we want to find out why it doesn't work in your environment. But this sounds strange: _nohup is executed after checking._ If the _checking_ is repeated long enough (by more runs of the loop or longer sleep time within), it cannot terminate before _nohup is executed_, won't you agree?

Comment: I did the same with `until` and it works. Thanks for the help!